# Chrome's "Save as" reloads page without POST

Tags: google-chrome

I have a small php example at http://codepad.org/EW9vh8sF .

It takes two variables, start and end, and POST them back to the same php-file, which then displays the two variables again.

When using the Save As... in Chrome (Version 29.0.1547.57 m), and choosing "Webpage, HTML Only" the saved file contains the default values of my two variables.

It appears to me that Chrome actually reloads the page without sending the variables earlier sent as POST, and then saves the reloaded page with the default values.

Firefox (Version 24.0) saves the page successfully.
Using Chrome and saving "Webpage, Complete" is also successful - my newly update variables are stored in the html-file.

When I changed to use GET instead of POST, it works as intended even on "HTML Only"-saves, but this is not a convenient solution.

This is tested on different computers with different versions of the browsers, and also on different webservers. The behaviour is the same regardless of platform.

Is there anything I can do programmatically to change this behaviour?

Comment: Nope.  Send a bug report to the Chrome team.

Comment: Behaviour is still the same - also useless for saving copies of error messages, thanks for the tip on saving as "Webpage, Complete".